# Shapes in hacklang

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

I have started learning hacklang today and now I am a bit stuck on shapes:
http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.shapes.php

I understand the concept of shapes and it seems really useful for me, but I can't understand why for example this code does not throw any error:

```
<?hh

type Point2D = shape('x' => int, 'y' => int);

function dotProduct(Point2D $a, Point2D $b): int {
    return $a['x'] * $b['x'] + $a['y'] * $b['y'];
}

function main_sse(): void {
    echo dotProduct(shape('x' => 3, 'y' => 'this should cause an fatal error?'), shape('x' => 4, 'y' => 4));
}

main_sse();
```

The 'y' key is defined as integer, but when I pass a string, no error is shown.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You also want "<?hh //strict" at the top of your file on new files, if at all possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually executing Hack code doesn't necessarily typecheck everything. You need to actually [run a separate tool to enforce the type system, as described in the docs article linked here](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/install.hack.bootstrapping.php). When you do that, you'll get an error that looks something like this, depending on the exact version of HHVM you have:

```
File "shapes.php", line 10, characters 19-23:
Invalid argument (Typing[4110])
File "shapes.php", line 3, characters 41-43:
This is an int
File "shapes.php", line 10, characters 42-76:
It is incompatible with a string
```

Modern versions of HHVM will also yell at you if you aren't running the typechecker; I suspect you're running an older version, before we realized this was a point of confusion -- sorry!

What actually happens when you run type-incorrect code is undefined behavior. The answer by Ed Cottrell is correct for the current version of HHVM -- we do the same thing PHP does to coerce types -- but keep in mind it's **undefined behavior** and may change in future versions without notice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Well currently I am using HipHop VM 3.3.0-dev+2014.08.22 (rel). To my knowledge it is the newest public version. Anyway, hope that HHVM will throw an exception or an error for this kind of type mismatch in the future :)

Answer (score 3):

The interpreter will try to evaluate the `'y'` key as a number to do the calculation.

Example:

```
echo 4 * '6';
// prints 24

echo 4 * '6foo';
// prints 24

echo 'foo' * 42;
// prints 0, because floatval('foo') === 0
```

Your situation is like the third example.  `floatval('this should cause an fatal error?') === 0`, so the calculation is:

```
$a['x'] * $b['x'] + $a['y'] * $b['y'] === 3 * 4 + 0 * 4 === 12
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) but what is the point of the shapes then? what is the point of defining that 'y' is integer? It works just like regular array.

Comment: I'm a little out of my depth here, having never played with hacklang. But clearly the interpreter is doing a conversion. I think the problem is that you are looking at the type definition for `Point2D`, but your `dotProduct` call uses `shape`, not `Point2D`, so the type check never occurs.

Comment: This is indeed a type error, you just need to actually look for type errors separately -- please see my answer for a full explanation.